# Placing the x-axes at a different y-value

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am overwhelmed by the customization options I have in Python. Is there a way to modify the x-axes to or add a x-axes at y=0 like in the Excel example? If not, is there a way to add an emphasized grid line?

Here are the python plot with x-axes at y=-0.10:

[image]

and the excel plot with x-axes at y=0:

[image]

The plot command is currently simply

```
plot = plt.plot(diff)
ax = plt.axes()
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

where `diff` stores the data be plotted.

Comment: Have a look at http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `set_position()` method of the `Spine` class:

```
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))
```